# Perl: averaging numbers in a file

Tags: perl

I have a file where each line consists of a numerical value:

```
1
2
3
3
1
```

My function looks something like this:

```
print "Enter file name to average \n";
$infile = <>;
open IN, "$infile";
$total = 0;
$count =0;
while (my $line = <>) {
      $total +=$line;
      $count ++=;
}
print "Average = ", $total / $count, "\n";
close(IN);
```

But I'm getting an error at the `$count ++=;` line saying that there's a syntax error near "+=;".

Comment: you should use `strict` and `warnings`.`$count++` only will work. No need for `=`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ideal code for your problem should look like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Enter file name to average \n";
chomp( my $infile = <> );    #remove new line characters
open my $IN, '<', $infile
  or die "unable to open file: $! \n"; #use 3 arg file open syntax
my $total = 0;
my $count = 0;
while ( my $line = <$IN> ) {## you should use <>  on file handle
    chomp $line;
    next if ($line=~/^\s*$/); #ignore blank lines
    $total += $line;
    $count++;
}

if($count > 0){
   print "Average = ", $total / $count, "\n";
}
else{
    print "Average cannot be calculated Check if file is blank \n";
}
close($IN);
```

Comment: Check if count is 0 before dividing by it

Answer (score 2):

Just do `$count++`, no `=`.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement.

Comment: After making this change and running my code again. I type in the file name, then there's a blank line and my program just stops. I press ctrl+C to quit and get an error saying that there's an illegal division by 0 at line 10 (which is the `print "Average = ", $total / $count, "\n";` line. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Change `$line = <>` to `$line = <IN>` and use `chomp $line` to remove newlines

Comment: @AruneshSingh Thank you. I realized that `$total / $count` gives me a fraction instead of a numerical value...is there a way to change this?

Comment: you can use [int](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html) or floor or ceil based on your requirement.

Comment: @AruneshSingh what if I want to keep the decimals?

Comment: The result is already in decimals. I thought you wanted to remove decimals.

Answer (score 0):

No need of `=` after increment `$count++`. In simple way you can do like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $total = 0;
my $count = 0;
while (<>)
{
    $total += $_;
    $count++;
}
print "Average = ", $total/$count, "\n";

_____file.txt_____
1
2
3
3
1
```

Execute you program as:

```
./scriptname file.txt
```

Output:

```
Average = 2
```